# A new data type element access in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I am new with haskell.
I have new types:

```
type RealName = String
type UserName = String
type GroupName = String
type Message = String
```

and

```
data User = User UserName RealName [UserName] [Post]
```

and in a new function I want to access the real name of a user;

```
accreal :: User -> RealName
accreal us = ??
```

How can I do it, I tried many ways but didnt work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use pattern matching:

```
accreal:: User -> RealName
accreal (User un rn uns ps) = rn
```

You might also want to prefix unused variables with `_` to suppress warnings.

```
accreal:: User -> RealName
accreal (User _un rn _uns _ps) = rn
```

You can also simply use `_` to discard a value, e.g. `accreal (User _ rn _  _) = rn`.

Alternatively, change your `data` type into a record:

```
data User = User 
   { user :: UserName
   , real :: RealName
   , others :: [UserName]
   , posts :: [Post] }
```

This automatically defines a projection `real :: User -> RealName` for you.

Comment: Is there any other way without using pattern matching